# Is it possible to store each Elasticsearch index in a custom folder?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the following issue,

For example, the next structure:

/**companyA**/user/mappings
/**companyA**/address/mappings

/**companyB**/user/mappings
/**companyB**/address/mappings

and many more...

is it possible to store the index "**companyA**" and "**companyB**" in different folders?

Supposing using Elasticsearch 6.0 or 5.6.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: is not mandatory to do this, but In my SaaS, each of our clients have it's own database, own Data, nothing is mixed, and I was hoping to do the same with our Elastic instance.

Comment: [ES is multi-tenant](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-multi-tenancy) ;-)